# Prevent Particles from falling

Tags: animation, particles, physics

I'm animating a space scene in Blender were to asteroids collide and explode. I used a particle system and an explode modifier to realize it. The only problem is that the particles fall down after exploding. Of course I want them not to fall because i want to simulate no gravity. I already gave the particles a mass of zero in the physics tab but they are still falling.

Does someone know how I can stop the particles falling?

Answer (score 2):

Since your scene takes place in space, there is no need for gravity. Disable *Gravity* in the *Scene Properties*:

[image: gravity setting]

Answer (score 2):

You can control the effect gravity has on the particle system under the Field Weights section: [image: particle field weight settings]

Comment: +1 That's possible, too. I disabled it for the whole scene because of the sentence "Of course I want them not to fall because i want to simulate no gravity." So I thought overall no gravity would fit the situation best instead of just disabling it on the particles.

Comment: Agreed, thought I'd include this answer as well since it's nice to have this fine level of control, I'd +1 your answer but my reps not high enough.

Comment: That's okay, no problem :)